# Remove the first element of the String array in Java : Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

Let say I have this String array `"{Unclaimed", "Lost/Stolen", "Damaged/Defective", "Pawned", "Not Turned Over", "Others"}` and I want to remove the first one which is `Unclaimed` , It will remove if `aat_distribution_status` is being clicked is there anyway to remove it? I tried `Reasons = Reasons.Skip(1).ToArray()` but it doesn't work

**My sample code**

```
AutoCompleteTextView aat_reason_not_presented;
aat_reason_not_presented = findViewById(R.id.aat_reason_not_presented);

String[] Reasons = new String[]{"Unclaimed", "Lost/Stolen", "Damaged/Defective", "Pawned", "Not Turned Over", "Others"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterYesNo = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Reasons);

adapterYesNo.setDropDownViewResource(simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
aat_reason_not_presented.setAdapter(adapterYesNo);

 aat_distribution_status.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {

                 Reasons = Reasons.Skip(1).ToArray() //Trying to remove first element of reasons but it didn't work

                }
            });
```

Comment: Arrays have *fixed size* so you can't "remove* some element since that would affect its size. You can *replace* that element with something else. So for instance if you have `{a, b, c}` and you want to get rid of `a` you can't modify *that* array into `{b, c}` (since now its size is 2 not 3), but what you can do is *shifting elements* and filling blanks with `null` like `{b, c, null}` (or use other values representing *no element*). To have array with reduced size you will need to create *new* array of that size and fill it with data you want. Alternatively you can use List which is resizable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange(T[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)) like

```
Reasons = Arrays.copyOfRange(Reasons, 1, Reasons.length);
```

Also, Java variable names start with a lowercase letter by convention. Finally, I suspect that `Reasons` must be effectively final to use it in the inner class like that. So I doubt that will work as is.